# Where can I find icons of LEGO bricks?

Tags: piece-information, part-database

I'm looking for a set of icons - maybe as SVG or something like that - for available bricks to use to label sorting boxes (non-commercial use)

Are the official brick icons used e.g. in build instructions somewhere available from LEGO or are there alternative sets available?

Comment: Are you looking for a few, or perhaps thousands of parts? Either way you might want to use renders of 3D models from the [LDraw parts library](http://www.ldraw.org/article/13.html).

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do with those icons, so we can better answer your question?

Comment: Well, actually I want to have them to use while labelling sorting boxes. So non commercial use

Answer (score 6):

### Rebrickable

For non-commercial use, the parts library used by [**Rebrickable**](https://rebrickable.com/search?po=1) is fairly extensive. More importantly the images have a very consistent presentation.

If you already know the part ID you can replace the use the URL below to get a direct link to the image. Just replace the X with your part ID.

```
https://img.rebrickable.com/img/pieces/elements/X.jpg
```

This won't work for parts that have alternative designs and some other exceptions.

[image]

---

### LEGO Pick A Brick

LEGO's official [**Pick A Brick**](https://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Pick-a-Brick) service has a relatively small collection of common pieces that are still in production. The images are of a consistently good quality although quite small.